# call function when notfication is clicked Android

Tags: android, notifications, onclicklistener

instead of opening activity, I found that the broadcast receiver can do the trick but it's not working its is not sending an intent to my broadcast receiver. I don't know any workaround. eventually, I have to call the notification from a service. please give me a way to run a function on clicking the notification

### Broadcast receiver class

```
class broadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "onReceive")

    }
}
```

### main activity code

```
receiver = broadcastReceiver()

registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter("com.example.andy.CUSTOM_INTENT"))

        notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val intent = Intent(this, broadcastReceiver::class.java)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 5, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        // RemoteViews are used to use the content of
        // some different layout apart from the current activity layout
        val contentView = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.activity_after_notification)

        // checking if android version is greater than oreo(API 26) or not
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, description, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
            notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.GREEN
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(false)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

            builder = Notification.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setContent(contentView)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.resources, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        } else {

            builder = Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContent(contentView)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.resources, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        }
        notificationManager.notify(1234, builder.build())
    }
```